# Varnish automagically adding load balancer IP to X-Forwarded-For header

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

My request flow is as follows;

```
HAProxy --> Varnish (4.0.1) --> Apache web backends
```

When a new request comes in to HAProxy, the client's IP address is being added to the `X-Forwarded-For` header (which is good!). However, it looks like Varnish is adding the `HAProxy` IP as well. When the request gets to my `vcl_recv` routine, the `X-Forwarded-For` header is:

```
X-Forwarded-For: end-user-ip, haproxy-ip
```

You can see that in the `varnishlog` output:

```
*   << Request  >> 8
-   Begin          req 7 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1409262358.542659 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1409262358.542659 0.000000 0.000000
-   ReqStart       192.168.1.103 48193
-   ReqMethod      PURGE
-   ReqURL         /some/path
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.1
-   ReqHeader      Authorization: Basic xxx
-   ReqHeader      User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
-   ReqHeader      Host: example.com
-   ReqHeader      Accept: */*
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 1.2.3.4
-   ReqHeader      Connection: close
-   ReqUnset       X-Forwarded-For: 1.2.3.4
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 1.2.3.4, 192.168.1.101
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   ReqUnset       X-Forwarded-For: 1.2.3.4, 192.168.1.101
-   VCL_acl        NO_MATCH purge_acl
-   Debug          "VCL_error(403, Not allowed.)"
-   VCL_return     synth
```

The reason I need the accurate client IP address is so I can check it against ACL rules for `PURGE`/`BAN`. Since the last IP in the `X-Forwarded-For` header is that of HAProxy, the ACL check fails for all IPs. Here is the relevant section of my config:

```
acl purge_acl {
    "1.2.3.4";
}

sub vcl_recv {

    set req.backend_hint = load_balancer.backend();

    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        if (!std.ip(req.http.X-forwarded-for, "0.0.0.0") ~ purge_acl) {
            return(synth(403, "Not allowed."));
        }
        ban("obj.http.x-url ~ " + req.url);
        return(synth(200, "Ban added"));
    }

}
```

Any ideas how I can rely solely on the `X-Forwarded-For` header from HAProxy, without Varnish tampering with it?

A side note, it seems that Varnish is doing exactly this **(although this IS NOT in mv VCL config)**:

```
if (req.restarts == 0) {
    if (req.http.X-Forwarded-For) {
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
    } else {
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I also bumped into this problem today.

The `default.vcl` in varnish 4.0 was renamed in `builtin.vcl` and does not contain the `set req.http.X-Forwarded-For` part that you mentioned - [link](https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/browser/bin/varnishd/builtin.vcl). Nevertheless he clearly appends to a comma separated list the intermediate proxy IP address as per the protocol specs - [Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For).

One solution would be to use the `X-Real-IP` header instead, overwriting this header all the time in HAProxy with the real client ip and using this one for vcl ACL.

Another solution as (wrongly) mentioned [in the varnish forum](https://www.varnish-cache.org/comment/1825#comment-1825), would be `regsub(req.http.X-Forwarded-For, "[, ].*$", "")` that takes the leftmost IP address. However, this method is **NOT SECURE**, since this header can be easily spoofed.

My suggestion would be to extract the known part, varnish IP from the header like this:

```
if (!std.ip(regsub(req.http.X-Forwarded-For, ", 192\.168\.1\.101$", ""), "0.0.0.0") ~ purge_acl) {
    return(synth(403, "Not allowed."));
}
```

The only problem with this is if there are more than 2 hops in the connection, eg. you also use a proxy to connect to internet. A good solution for this is provided by `nginx` since you can define trusted hops, and they are ignored recursively until the real client ip.

```
set_real_ip_from 192.168.1.101;
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
real_ip_recursive on;
```

You can see more details about this in this [serverfault thread answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/314574/nginx-real-ip-header-and-x-forwarded-for-seems-wrong/414166#414166)

You might also want to check why in your `VCL_call RECV` you do a `ReqUnset X-Forwarded-For` BEFORE the ACL match.

Answer (score 11):

Varnish appends its default logic to any functions you define such as `vcl_recv` rather than purely overriding it. The default `vcl_recv` logic contains:

```
if (req.http.x-forwarded-for) {
    set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
} else {
    set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
}
```

as you noticed. What seems strange to me is that it seems like the Varnish default logic in `vcl_recv` is executing ahead of your `vcl_recv` logic. What value do you see for `X-Forwarded-For` within `vcl_deliver` if you define your own?

One thing you could do is parse out the first IP address like this where necessary:

```
set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = regsub(req.http.X-Forwarded-For, "^([^,]+),?.*$", "\1");
```

Comment: This answer helped me the most.

Comment: This answer does not hold for Varnish 4.x and upwards. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40840890/11303

Answer (score 3):

The Vanish source code has moved to GitHub so, for reference, since version 4.0 the X-Forwarded-For logic has been moved out of the `builtin.vcl`, (formerly `default.vcl`), and the source logic can be found in [bin/varnishd/cache/cache_req_fsm.c](https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/blob/4.0/bin/varnishd/cache/cache_req_fsm.c#L724).